# Reactjs - How can I duplicate a prop?

Tags: reactjs

So I've done some reading on here and saw that most people recommended *against* modifying props. Thus, I was wondering if there's a way I can duplicate the prop?

Essentially, I want to duplicate the prop and set it to the state. More specifically, I'm creating a table and one of the props that is passed in is the `headers` which is an array of objects

```
headers={[
            {id: "Name" , numeric: false, disablePadding: false, label: "Name"},
            { id: 'Weight', numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: 'Weight' },
            { id: 'Height', numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: 'Height' }
}]
```

I want to add a default column s.t. it'll look like

```
headers={[
            {id: "Name" , numeric: false, disablePadding: false, label: "Name"},
            { id: 'Weight', numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: 'Weight' },
            { id: 'Height', numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: 'Height' },
            {id: "Modify" , numeric: false, disablePadding: false, label: "Modify"}
              ]}
```

Thanks for your help! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few techniques you could use without using additional libraries
1. Set the initial state properly

```
this.state = { headers: this.props.headers.slice(0) }
```

2. When modifying the state use the callback technique

   this.setState((previousState) => {
         // mutate the state a return a new one.
         });

[How to use slice](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-clone-array)

[Using setState properly](https://medium.com/@voonminghann/when-to-use-callback-function-of-setstate-in-react-37fff67e5a6c)

Answer (score 1):

Do this in constructor:

```
this.state: {fooCopy: this.props.foo};
```

if you want to store modified prop in state, then make a copy in a local var (try Object.assign or JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a))), modify it, and then store in state.

Comment: Javascript objects are passed by reference. `fooCopy.baz = 'bazzz'` will also set `this.props.foo.baz` to `'bazzz'`.

Comment: *"Do this in constructor:"* No....should not use `setState` in constructor. Just create the state object there

Answer (score 1):

Array object is passed by reference. Instead you can create a new array and then dump the data into the state.

```
this.state = {
  headers: (() => {
    return [...this.props.headers, {id: "Modify" , numeric: false, disablePadding: false, label: "Modify"}]
  })()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the component which you have to add.

```
let newObject = { "id": "Modify" , "numeric": false, "disablePadding": false, "label": "Modify" }
```

Now, create a duplicate along with the newObject which was created.

```
const headers = [...this.props.headers, newObject]
```

Now, set that headers to state variable header.

```
this.setState({
 header: headers
})
```

I hope this will work for you.